# Is there an algorithm for sampling shortest paths?

Tags: algorithms, sampling, search

I have a triangle matrix NxN of distances between vertices (vertex i connected only with vectices j>i) and I'd like to sample path from first to the last and use it as a training sample. Is there an algorithm to do it? Would swapping min->sample in A* be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this answers your question. But have a look in these algorithms:

**The Shortest Path Faster Algorithm (SPFA)** is an improvement of the Bellman–Ford algorithm which computes single-source shortest paths in a weighted directed graph. The algorithm is believed to work well on random sparse graphs and is particularly suitable for graphs that contain negative-weight edges.

**Dijkstra's algorithm** solves the shortest-path problem for any weighted, directed graph with non-negative weights. It can handle graphs consisting of cycles, but negative weights will cause this algorithm to produce incorrect results.

The Shortest Path algorithm calculates the shortest (weighted) path between a pair of nodes. In this category, Dijkstra's algorithm is the most well known. It is a real time graph algorithm, and can be used as part of the normal user flow in a web or mobile application.

More Info at:

1. https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/shortest-path-problem
2. https://medium.com/basecs/finding-the-shortest-path-with-a-little-help-from-dijkstra-613149fbdc8e
3. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-05813-9_9